# Stamped date format using lubridate is selecting the wrong fixed format

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to format date output using `stamp` from the `lubridate` package. I would like the end format to be similar to

> Sunday, November 1, 23:15

My problem is getting the unabbreviated month to be printed

```
library(lubridate)
x <- ymd_hm("2017-11-20 15:15")
```

Now if I use `stamp` as below then I almost get the right output

```
stamp("Sunday, November 30, 23:15")(x)
Multiple formats matched: "%A, %B %d, %y:%H"(1), "%A, %B %y, %d:%H"(1), "Sunday, %B %d, %y:%H"(1), "Sunday, %B %y, %d:%H"(1)
Using: "%A, %B %d, %y:%H"
[1] "Monday, November 20, 17:15"
```

However, November is interpreted as fixed text and the guessed format uses the year and hour in place of the hour and minutes. If I add the `orders` argument then I can try to force the order of the inputs

```
stamp("Sunday, Nov 30, 23:15", orders="AbdHM")(x)
Multiple formats matched: "%A, %Om %d, %H:%M"(0), "%A, %b %d, %H:%M"(1)
Using: "%A, %Om %d, %H:%M"
[1] "Monday, 11 20, 15:15"
```

Here the output is correct except I get the month as a number and not as text. Note that `stamp` does provide the correct format but ends up using the not-quite-correct-format despite being given an identical match.

What can I do to force `stamp` to use the exact format that I supplied?

[There are other options than using `stamp`. I just cannot figure out why the code above isn't working]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question to the `lubridate` package developers on [GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/545). It turns out the formatting error described above is a bug which has now been fixed. I'll add the answer here since the (current) documentation for `lubridate` does not present a lot of information on the `orders` and `locale` arguments.

If you have version 1.6.0.9009 or higher of `lubridate` then I now get

```
stamp("Sunday, Nov 30, 23:15", orders="AbdHM")(x)
Multiple formats matched: "%A, %b %d, %H:%M"(1), "%A, %Om %d, %H:%M"(0)
Using: "%A, %b %d, %H:%M"
[1] "Monday, Nov 20, 15:15"
```

which is as desired (notice the abbreviated month). If the locale or time zone is given then the recent version of `lubridate` works

```
stamp("Sunday, November 1, 16:15", orders="ABdHM")(force_tz(x,  "Europe/Copenhagen"))
Multiple formats matched: "%A, %B %d, %H:%M"(1), "%A, %Om %d, %H:%M"(0)
Using: "%A, %B %d, %H:%M"
[1] "Monday, November 20, 15:15"
```

The correct output can also be obtained by setting the `locale` argument.

```
stamp("Sunday, November 30, 23:15", "ABdHM", locale = "en_DK.utf8")
```